# 301 permanent redirect with extensions and sub folders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I tried to permanent redirect 301 from http://example.com to http://example1.com

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^submitticket\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/test\.example1\.com\/contact\.php$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/manage\.example1\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

If i set any link like http://example.com/index.php to http://example1.com/index.php it won't redirect

How can i made a permanent redirect files with all extensions and directory included ?

Comment: Is the intent to just redirect for `submitticket.php` and `/`, or all links?  The config you have will just do those two specific locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate vhost for example.com and put this in the config file:

```
ServerName example.com
Redirect permanent / http://example1.com/
```

Remember the trailing slash. This will redirect any request to the other domain, including subfolders, files and such.